# pytest.PytestDeprecationWarning Ошибка при проверке кода pytest-pep8

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

Читал книгу "Изучаем программирование на Python автор Бэрри П.".

В книге было задание проверить код на соответствие правилам PEP8.

По инструкции в книге я установил **pytest** `pip install pytest` и плагин к нему **pytest-pep8** `pip install pytest-pep8`. Все установилось успешно.

Далее я запустил проверку своего модуля в командной строке `py.test --pep8 D:\code\HeadFirst\webapp\vsearch.py` результат:

```
C:\Users\titelivus>py.test --pep8 D:\code\HeadFirst\webapp\vsearch.py
c:\python\lib\site-packages\pep8.py:110: FutureWarning: Possible nested set at position 1
  EXTRANEOUS_WHITESPACE_REGEX = re.compile(r'[[({] | []}),;:]')
============================= test session starts ==============================
platform win32 -- Python 3.8.3, pytest-6.0.1, py-1.9.0, pluggy-0.13.1
rootdir: C:\Users\titelivus
plugins: pep8-1.0.6
collected 0 items / 1 error

==================================== ERRORS ====================================
________________________ ERROR collecting test session _________________________
c:\python\lib\site-packages\pluggy\hooks.py:286: in __call__
    return self._hookexec(self, self.get_hookimpls(), kwargs)
c:\python\lib\site-packages\pluggy\manager.py:93: in _hookexec
    return self._inner_hookexec(hook, methods, kwargs)
c:\python\lib\site-packages\pluggy\manager.py:84: in <lambda>
    self._inner_hookexec = lambda hook, methods, kwargs: hook.multicall(
c:\python\lib\site-packages\pytest_pep8.py:38: in pytest_collect_file
    return Pep8Item(path, parent, pep8ignore, config._max_line_length)
c:\python\lib\site-packages\_pytest\nodes.py:95: in __call__
    warnings.warn(NODE_USE_FROM_PARENT.format(name=self.__name__), stacklevel=2)
E   pytest.PytestDeprecationWarning: Direct construction of Pep8Item has been deprecated, please use Pep8Item.from_parent.
E   See https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/deprecations.html#node-construction-changed-to-node-from-parent for more details.
=========================== short test summary info ============================
ERROR  - pytest.PytestDeprecationWarning: Direct construction of Pep8Item has ...
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Interrupted: 1 error during collection !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
=============================== 1 error in 0.14s ===============================
```

Я внимательно прочитал текст ошибки, перешел по указанной ссылке, прочитал ее решение, но оно для меня не было понятным.

Нужно в каком то файле (догадываюсь что здесь `c:\python\lib\site-packages\pytest_pep8.py:38: in pytest_collect_file`), что-то изменить, чтобы все заработало.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Update

Невнимательно прочитал вопрос, исправляюсь! Проблема `pytest-pep8` с версией `pytest>=6.0`, поскольку deprecations, введенные в версиях 5.Х, с версии 6.0 начинают кидать исключения. В данном случае речь идет о [Node Construction changed to `Node.from_parent`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/deprecations.html#node-construction-changed-to-node-from-parent). В качестве костыля можно использовать небольшой патч:

```diff
diff --git a/pytest_pep8.py b/pytest_pep8.py
index 6e6cd7e..0b7ad62 100644
--- a/pytest_pep8.py
+++ b/pytest_pep8.py
@@ -35,7 +35,7 @@ def pytest_collect_file(path, parent):
     if config.option.pep8 and path.ext == '.py':
         pep8ignore = config._pep8ignore(path)
         if pep8ignore is not None:
-            return Pep8Item(path, parent, pep8ignore, config._max_line_length)
+            return Pep8Item.from_parent(fspath=path, parent=parent, pep8ignore=pep8ignore, max_line_length=config._max_line_length)


 def pytest_sessionfinish(session):
@@ -50,8 +50,8 @@ class Pep8Error(Exception):

 class Pep8Item(pytest.Item, pytest.File):

-    def __init__(self, path, parent, pep8ignore, max_line_length):
-        super(Pep8Item, self).__init__(path, parent)
+    def __init__(self, fspath, parent, pep8ignore, max_line_length):
+        super(Pep8Item, self).__init__(fspath, parent)
         self.add_marker("pep8")
         self.pep8ignore = pep8ignore
         self.max_line_length = max_line_length
```

Пример использования: сохрани сниппет в файл (к примеру, `changes.patch`) и используй либо `patch`, либо `git` для применения патча:

```
> python -c "import site; print(site.getsitepackages()[0])"
```

выдаст путь, в котором установлен `pytest-pep8` и лежит файл `pytest_pep8.py`. Теперь примени патч:

```
> patch -d путь/к/site-packages -p1 < сhanges.patch
```

либо

```
> git apply changes.patch --no-index --directory=путь/к/site-packages
```

(я не пользуюсь Windows, поэтому не могу сказать, как настроить эти программы под ней)

Либо просто открой файл `pytest_pep8.py`, найдешь его с помощью

```
> python -c "import pytest_pep8; print(pytest_pep8.__file__)"
```

и поменяй строки, руководствуясь патчем (пары минус-плюс подскажут, какую строку нужно заменить на какую).

Comment: Ваш ответ не связан с моей проблемой, пожалуйста прочтите внимательно мою проблему.

Comment: @titelivus извиняюсь, ступил. Посмотри обновленный ответ, должно помочь.

Comment: Большое спасибо! Проблема решена.

Comment: Рад был помочь!