# Тестирование модуля на соответствие PEP8

Tags: python, windows-10, командная-строка, pep8

Всем доброго времени суток.  У меня такая проблема. Изучаю python по учебнику Пола Берри 2017 г. издания. Согласно заданию, мне необходимо было протестировать модуль на соответствие требованиям PEP 8, в командной строку (ОС Windows 10). Мною в командной строке(предварительно открытой в папке с модулем) был введён код: pytest --pep8 vsearch.py(название моего модуля). Однако вылезла ошибка, что конструкция Pep8Item устарела и необходимо пользоваться конструкцией Pep8Items.from_parent.  Посмотрел в документации не смог разобраться. Будьте добры объясните, что означает комбинация PEP8Items.from_parent, на примере моего задания. Буду очень благодарен.
P.s. Обучаюсь совсем недавно, ещё очень многого не знаю. Прошу строго не судить)

Comment: Ваш случай? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1164493/pytest-pytestdeprecationwarning-%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-pytest-pep8

Comment: Нет. Проблема в другом. Не могу понять, как писать конструкцию Pep8Item.from_parent в командной строке.

Comment: Поставьте более старую версию pytest. <6

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Просто хотелось бы разобраться, как работать в новой версии pytest.

Answer (score 0):

Если вопрос еще актуален, то теперь вместо py.test --pep8 используется новый модуль pycodestyle
В командной строке просто прописываете pycodestyle и имя файла.py